# Factorial in D Language

Tags: d

I have just started with D and was trying to write a simple factorial program in D. Is there anything like vectors of C++ in D? I wanted to use vectors to create a dynamic function to compute factorial.

Comment: I haven't used D lang but did you refer to the [documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/spec.html)? It says something about dynamic arays [here](https://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#dynamic-arrays) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In D, dynamic arrays are resizable and can be concatenated, just like vectors in C++.
Here is an example with such array which reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`:

```d
import std.stdio;  // for readf and writeln

void main ()  // void for main means "int with return 0 at exit" to OS
{
    int n;
    readf (" %s", &n);  // skip whitespace, then read int in default format
    auto f = [1];  // a dynamic array of int containing a 1
    foreach (i; 1..n + 1)  // for i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n - 1, n
    {
        f ~= f[$ - 1] * i;  // append to f its last element multiplied by i
    }
    writeln (f);  // print the dynamic array in default format
}
```

For input

```
10
```

the output is:

```
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

As mentioned in the comments, refer to [the documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#dynamic-arrays) for more information on built-in dynamic arrays.

---

However, it is not clear what is a *dynamic function* you mention.
And, generally, we don't need an array or vector to calculate factorial.
Check [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial#D) for a few other approaches to calculating factorial in D.

Comment: @DejanLekic: Yeah, factorial is in fact one of the examples for [std.range.recurrence](https://dlang.org/library/std/range/recurrence.html). However, the question involved arrays for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [std.bigint](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_bigint.html)? - it's optimized for arbitrary-precision numerics. Even with `ulong` (`2^64`) you can only compute factorial until 20 and for this use-case an inline-table might make more sense. Here's an example with `BigInt`:

```d
import std.bigint : BigInt;

BigInt factorial(int n)
{
    auto b = BigInt(1);
    foreach (i; 1..n + 1)
        b *= i;
    return b;
}

void main ()
{
    import std.stdio : writeln;
    factorial(10).writeln; // 3628800
    factorial(100).writeln; // 9.33 * 10^157
}
```

If you want to learn more about dynamic arrays, maybe the DLang Tour pages for [Arrays](http://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/basics/arrays) or [Slices](http://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/basics/slices) might help you?